# My void "fi()" function somehow ended my program immediately

Tags: c++

Here is my code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

const int maxarr = 1e7 +5;
bool a[maxarr];

void fi()
{
    memset(a, false, sizeof(a));
    a[1] = true;
    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= maxarr; i++)
    {
        sum += i;
        a[sum] = true;

    }
}
void solve()
{
    long n;
    cin >> n;
    if(a[n] == true) cout<<1<<endl;
    else cout<<0<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    /*ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);
    freopen("TRIANGULAR.INP", "r", stdin);
    freopen("TRIANGULAR.OUT", "w", stdout);*/
    long t;
    cin >> t;
    fi();
    for(int i = 1; i <= t; i++)
    {
        solve();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it only work until I input my t variable, the rest doesnt work at all.

I have tried to move the fi() call function around and identified the problem is within it, but I have looked closely and see nothing wrong with it.

```
int main()
{
    /*ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);
    freopen("TRIANGULAR.INP", "r", stdin);
    freopen("TRIANGULAR.OUT", "w", stdout);*/
    fi();
    long t;
    cin >> t;
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= t; i++)
    {
        solve();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I called it before cin my t variable and it imediately ended the program. Thank for your help.

Comment: `memset(a, false, sizeof(a));` is unecessary, global variables are zero-initialized.

Comment: `i <= maxarr` - any good book teaches that this leads to the invalid index for the array subscript.

Comment: Do you think the sum of all of the numbers from 1 to `maxarr` might be larger than `maxarr`? You're going past the end of the array, way past.

Comment: Does it make the script stop working? I expected it would go past maxarr, but I don't think that is the reason the script ended the program, I will try to lower maxarr and see what would happen, thank.

Comment: The sum of 1 to 10,000,005 is 50,000,055,000,015. An `int` isn't large enough to hold that number so the sum overflows (which is undefined behavior) when it passes 2,147,483,647 so at that point `a[sum] = true;` is accessing the array about 2.13 *billion* elements past the end. Once the overflow happens and the int goes negative (assumption, it'll never get this far) it will access the array about 2.14 *billion* bytes before the beginning. So yes, that is the reason the code crashes.

Comment: Lowering `maxarr` will not help. The sum of the numbers will always be larger than that. Whatever exercise you are trying to solve you've chosen the wrong method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your loop in `fi()` is accessing an element past the end of `a`.   That is undefined behaviour.   Array indexing in C++ is zero based, not one-based.  So, if an array has size `n`, the last element has index `n-1`, not `n`.      Also, unrelated, initialising an `int` with `1e7 +5`  (a floating point value) is very bad technique.   Use `10000005` is you must (and bear in mind that an `int` is not guaranteed able to represent values larger than `32767`).

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) | [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3):

Let's make `maxarr` lower for the sake of simplicity, and step through it to understand what's actually happening.

```cpp
const int maxarr = 10;
bool a[maxarr]; // [1]

void fi()
{
    memset(a, false, sizeof(a)); //[2]
    a[1] = true;
    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= maxarr; i++) //[3]
    {
        sum += i; //[4]
        a[sum] = true; //[5]
    }
}
```

At `[1]`, we create `a` with ***10*** elements. By default, these will be initialised to `false` (any global variables are init'd to 0).

At `[2]` we `memset` to false, which is redundant but besides the point.

At `[3]` we iterate from the second element onwards. Before this, `a` looks like the following:

```
[false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
               \_ This is where the loop at [3] will begin
```

Let's consider `[4]` and `[5]` for each value that `i` will take:

| i | sum (after `[4]`) |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 5 | 15 |
| 6 | 21 |
| 7 | 28 |
| 8 | 36 |
| 9 | 45 |
| 10 | 55 |

Now, remember that at `[1]`, we create an array of  ***10*** elements. This means that it is valid for indices `0` through `9` (9 being the last element).

Notice at `[5]`, how we access `a[sum]`. What do you think will happen when `i>=4` (look at the table).

Let's take `i=6`. `[5]` results in `a[21] = true`, which is clearly invalid as we only have 10 elements.

In all honesty I have no idea what you're trying to do here, so I can't exactly offer a solution that will work for your use case, but in my eyes this looks like a design issue. I suggest drawing out whatever it is you're trying to solve, and draw out what data you need to store, how much space that will take relative to whatever etc, and then start writing code for it :-)